# Use nodejs to subscribe to ActiveMQ STOMP while using Message Selectors?

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic

I want to subscribe to an activemq server using nodejs. The problem I have is that right now, my node-stomp-client (https://github.com/easternbloc/node-stomp-client) is currently getting all the messages that are being published out of MQ, when I really want to use "Message Selector" so that I don't get all the messages coming to nodejs. Is there a way I can use message selectors in nodejs like you could do with Java subscribing to ActiveMQ? (Message Selectors reference in Java: http://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml)

Comment: pretty sure you could work something with `patrun` if you formatted your messages properly.

Answer (score 1):

In STOMP when subscribing to an ActiveMQ broker you can include a JMS style message selector in the options value that accompanies the subscribe call using the option name "selector".  The broker will then apply the selector and filter the messages sent to your client's subscription.

Refer to the ActiveMQ [STOMP documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html).

From the STOMP client website the subscribe takes headers as an argument.

```
var Stomp = require('stomp-client');
var destination = '/queue/someQueueName';
var client = new Stomp('127.0.0.1', 61613, 'user', 'pass');

client.connect(function(sessionId) {
    client.subscribe(destination, function(body, headers) {
        console.log('This is the body of a message on the subscribed queue:', body);
    });

    client.publish(destination, 'Oh herrow');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am not sure how this translates to something in a nodejs library.

Comment: I don't do javascript so I can't help with Node.js but I'm sure if you give it a try or maybe employ some Google searches you can figure it out.

Comment: No one has done it it seems, even though I can see how you can do it with Java classes and XML. Hopefully someone can shed some light.